# Android bitmap low quality background

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, jpeg

I have a jpg coming from a url:

[image]

When I get the bitmap from the URL

```
setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap())
```

and add it to an imageView I get the following where the background appears dissorted

[image]

Comment: And what is `response`? How you get that object? There is no people who can read thoughts.

Comment: Response is a Volley ImageLoaded response, I tested it and is returning the correct bitmap without distortion.

Comment: post your code here, only then we will be able to help.

Comment: the second bitmap shows more pixels (on the bottom and on the left side) than the first, so they are two different bitmaps

Comment: I cropped the original images to show the difference between the two... apologies if I didn't crop them to the exact pixels.